# VHDL initialize vector (the length is not a multiple of 4) in hex

Tags: initialization, vhdl, stdvector

For example, I have a vector which length is 10.
How can I initialize it in hex. (The synthesize tool complains size mismatch as it thinks the hex value is a multiple of 4)

```
signal v : std_logic_vector (9 downto 0)    := x"11A";
```

Many thanks!
Nigong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a possible workaround is to write multiples of 4 bits as hex value and add the rest in binary, e.g.:

```
signal v: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := "01" & X"1A";
```

Answer (score 15):

`x"11A"` is a "hexadecimal bit string literal". Prior to VHDL-2008, these had to be a multiple of 4 bits, hence the problem you're seeing. VHDL-2008 removed this restriction, so you can now write `10x"11A"`. I don't know how much tool support there is for 2008, though.

Comment: I need to read more about VHDL 2008. Seems to be full of useful features :)

Comment: There's a good quick summary at the Doulos site - http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no "direct" way to achieve what you're looking for. You could use the following which is valid VHDL.

```
constant init : std_logic_vector (11 downto 0) := X"11A";
signal v : std_logic_vector (9 downto 0) := init(9 downto 0);
```

Comment: or more portably, `:= init(v'range);`

Comment: My initial answer contained the `v'range` part, but I tried to compile it and got an `Unknown identifier "v"` error. Seems like as long as my compiler hasn't parsed to entire line it doesn't know about `v`.

Comment: ah that's probably right. If there's more than one thing v's size I make a subtype for it (v_type or dataword or some descriptive type name.) Then dataword'range WOULD work there.

Answer (score 1):

Another variety of ugly hack:

```
constant init : natural := 16#11A#;
signal v : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(init, 10));
```

Having written that, I think it's the worst of the options offered, but I leave it here as a possibility!